# Out of bounds error

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Im getting this error saying

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at J4.writefile(J4_2_MultiDimensionalArray7.java:30)
    at J4.main(J4_2_MultiDimensionalArray7.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

What does this error mean? My program is to write the coordinates generated by the program to another file.
The program compiles but it does not run.
How can I fix this error?

Thanks!

Heres the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class J4
{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        int numpoints = 100, dimension = 2, length = 100;//numpoints is set to 100, dimension is set to 2, length is set to 100

        //arrays are initializewd and declared
        double [] lengthscale = new double [dimension];
        double [][] locations = new double [numpoints][dimension];

        PrintWriter fileOut = new PrintWriter (new FileWriter ("arrayNumPoints.txt"));

        writefile(lengthscale, locations, numpoints, dimension, length);


        for(int m=0; m <length; m++){//for loop
            fileOut.println(Arrays.toString(locations[m]) + ", ");//writes to file
        }
        fileOut.close ();//close file

    }//end main

    public static Double writefile(double lengthscale[], double locations[][], int dimension, int numpoints, int length)throws IOException
    {

        for (int a = 0; a < dimension; a++){//for loop runs while a is less than dimension
            lengthscale[a] = length;//stores array
        }//end for loop

        for (int x=0; x < numpoints; x++){//for loop runs while x is less than numpoints
            for (int y=0; y < dimension; y++){//nested for loop runs while y is less than dimension
                locations [x][y]= (2 * Math.random() - 1) * lengthscale[y];//creates the range and choses random point within 
                return locations[x][y];

            }//end nested for loop
        }//end for loop

        //if program doesnt run through loop.. alternative return statement (but
        double b= 1;    
        return b;
    }//end writefile methos
}//end
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: We can't help you with an answer if you don't show us the code, but from the error it is clear that you're trying to access a location in an array that hasn't been defined. Example: you have `array[5]` (5 elements) and you're trying to access `array[6]` which is, as you can see, out of bounds

Comment: Because you're trying to access an array at an out of bounds index.

Comment: Can we see your code? (Also, point out which line is line 30.)

Comment: The first line says it all `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: It is happening because you are calling an index that is out of bounds, let's say you have a 3 size array and you call for the fourth element.

Comment: You have removed the format to the stack trace, now you just need to point out the line 30.

Comment: You don't need to pass dimension you can use array.length instead.

Comment: @porfiriopartida @Dennis Meng line 30 is `lengthscale[a] = length;`

Comment: See the answer I just wrote. You are swapping your dimension and numpoints arguments when calling writefile..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
for (int a = 0; a < dimension; a++) {// for loop runs while a is less than dimension
  lengthscale[a] = length;// stores array
}// end for loop
```

with

```
for (int a = 0; a < lengthscale.length; a++) {// for loop runs while a is less than dimension
  lengthscale[a] = length;// stores array
}// end for loop
```

You cannot ensure that "dimension" is the real length of your array but you can be sure that array.length is

However the root cause of your error is that you have this:

```
writefile(lengthscale, locations, numpoints, dimension, length);
```

But this is how you have defined the method:

```
writefile(double lengthscale[], double locations[][], int dimension,
      int numpoints, int length)
```

You are swapping dimension with numpoints.

You can replace your code with:

```
..
    PrintWriter fileOut = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("arrayNumPoints.txt"));
    writefile(lengthscale, locations, dimension, numpoints, length);
    for (int m = 0; m < length; m++) {// for loop
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Even without seeing your code, I can tell that you are attempting to access index `2` of an array.  Because it's out of bounds, the array must be of length `2` or less.  Remember that valid array indices are `0` through `length - 1`.